# Compare two lists in excel and find uniques and dupes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

There are two lists I need to compare, see the below pic:

[image: Lists]

What I want to do is compare if each ID AND Option in left list exists or not in the right list. I tried to use VLOOKUP and COUNTIF but I dont know how to deal with the AND condition(ID AND Option) in both of them.

How can I do this?

Comment: So, in your example, `9881 4104` should not match, but `9881 3918` and `9881 3906` should match? (ignoring the other values for the time being).

Comment: This is tagged as excel 2010, you could use Countifs: `=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,H2,L:L,I2)>0,"Duplicate","Unique")`

Comment: @Jerry yes thats correct

Comment: @tigeravatar thats perfect! Thank you! If you could add that as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(K:K,H2,L:L,I2)>0,"Duplicate","Unique")
```